# Unable to retrieve date columns in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am finding difficulty when it comes to retrieving date values in hive. I am using esri git hub tools for hadoop and my final objective is to display these columns in arcmap.
My query is

```
> create external table test1(DISPLAYSCALE int, CREATED_DATE date, LAST_EDITED_DATE date)
> ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde'
> STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.esri.json.hadoop.UnenclosedJsonInputFormat'
> OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

When I try to use the select * query, I get the following error

> select * from test1 limit5;
>   Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DateWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

As per the json the datatype for  CREATED_DATE and  CREATED_DATE are esriFieldTypeDate and the values are in this format say 2013-11-20 09:39:25.000001.
So i used the date datatype while creating the table, copied it to HDFS using the unenclosed json and used the select * query to retrieve the columns, but I get the above error.
To get the values we are creating the same table with string data type respectively instead of date and we are able to get the values .
I tried it with different columns including shape attributes but the initial step of selecting the query itself is not working and am not able to proceed further

Can you suggest a solution for this problem. This question may seem silly but I am pretty new to programming.

Comment: I think this would be better on Stack Exchange or dba.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. maybe I coined it a bit incorrect.
Since I am using esri git hub tools for hadoop to convert features to json and copy to hdfs in arcmap toolbox I posted it on gis stack exchange, it is integral to gis since our objective is to display these columns along with the shape on arcmap.

Comment: OK, fair enough, edit the question to make it clear that you are dealing with geo data in ESRI Hadoop and nominate for reopening the question.

Comment: Looks like I got a different exception with the code on git master - https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/issues/101

Comment: With Spatial-Framework-For-Hadoop v1.2+, use `.....EsriJsonSerDe` and `....UnenclosedEsriJsonInputFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

`EsriJsonSerDe` (and `GeoJsonSerDe`) support for DATE and TIMETAMP type columns is [added on Spatial-Framework-for-Hadoop master in git](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/pull/124).

Alternately, you can try using `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe` or `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe` (instead of EsriJsonSerDe - and with column type `string` rather than `binary`) together with `UnenclosedEsriJsonInputFormat`.

[disclosure: Spatial-Framework-for-Hadoop collaborator]